# TensorFlow DNNClassifier Feature column

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning

I've successfully used the mnist dataset from tensorflow on a deep neural network model which I've coded from scratch. Now I wanted to try using the much simpler DNNClassifier function available in tensorflow. There are two problem I'm facing which I can't seem to find a solution on the internet

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/tmp/data/", one_hot=True)


estimator = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
    feature_columns=[28,9], #WTH is this!?!!
    hidden_units=[28, 512, 9],
    optimizer=tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(
        learning_rate=0.1,
    ))
x,y =mnist.train.next_batch(500)


estimator.train(input_fn=x,y,steps = 100)
```

1. There is one parameter tied to DNNClassifier which is feature_columns. The documentation for it doesn't make sense to me. What is feature_columns? What role does it play in the deep neural network? What type of variable should be given? (list,tuple,numpy array?)
2. How do I feed the training data into the estimator? I couldn't get past the feature_columns problem so I wasn't able to get the estimator working, which means I can't get the training to work. But I believe my current coding is the wrong way to do it.

Comment: Follow this tutorial: https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/estimator. It does exactly what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

The variable creates the feature_columns, which specifies the input to the model. Not sure why an array would be used for the variable, it should be tf.feature_column.numeric_column since all of the input features are numeric in mnist.

As far as feeding the data, the tensorflow people seem to be exclusively implementing input functions, which make feeding AND formatting the data far easier.

I have found the documentation to be helpful, sometimes. It looks like you have assembled various pieces into your code, and that not all of them are compatible. For instance, the canned estimators do not accept a learning rate input. Too, the number of hidden units far exceed what is necessary, unless you enjoy watching your processor push it's fans to the limit.

The developers blog is written in a clear, thorough manner. I would recommend starting with the blog to learn how to use the 'canned' Estimators. It's really clear and easy to use for adapting machine learning to your own data sets.

See this;
https://developers.googleblog.com/2017/09/introducing-tensorflow-datasets.html

Answer (score 1):

I tried to use the sample code of SQLFlow to explain what is "feature_columns".

show dataset:

```sql
SELECT * from iris.train limit 2;

-----------------------------
+--------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+-------+
| SEPAL LENGTH | SEPAL WIDTH | PETAL LENGTH | PETAL WIDTH | CLASS |
+--------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+-------+
|          6.4 |         2.8 |          5.6 |         2.2 |     2 |
|            5 |         2.3 |          3.3 |           1 |     1 |
+--------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+-------+
```

Training script:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM iris.train
TRAIN DNNClassifier
WITH n_classes = 3, hidden_units = [10, 20]
COLUMN sepal_length, sepal_width, petal_length, petal_width  /* This is "feature_columns" */
LABEL class
INTO sqlflow_models.my_dnn_model;
```

FYI:https://github.com/sql-machine-learning/sqlflow/blob/develop/doc/demo.md#training-a-dnnclassifier-and-run-prediction